# TCmalloc CPUPROFILE has no output

Tags: c++, memory-management, dynamic-linking, tcmalloc

I am currently interested in user-level memory allocator and TCmalloc from google.

I saw [this](http://goog-perftools.sourceforge.net/doc/tcmalloc.html) page that shows some evaluation to comparing PTmalloc2 and TCmalloc.

I want to rebuild that experiment in my environment.

So, I installed TCmalloc from an official reference from [here](https://google.github.io/tcmalloc/).

and also install golang for using profiling tool that called 'pprof'
to this command

```
sudo snap install --classic go
```

then, install google-pprof tools

```
go install github.com/google/pprof@latest
```

above command get from [here](https://github.com/google/pprof)

finally, I just tested TCmalloc with Tensorflow [MNIST python code](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/quickstart/advanced?hl=en) using `LD_PRELOAD`

```
   LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libtcmalloc.so.4 python3 MNIST.py
```

It works.

And Generated heap profile binary(.heap)

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libtcmallo.so.4 HEAPPROFILE=log python3 MNIST.py
```

It works too.

[generated .heap file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fp2kV.png)

Analyzing by using google-pprof also works.

And tried `CPUPROFILE` with under code

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libtcmallo.so.4 CPUPROFILE=cpu python3 MNIST.py
```

It didn't work. There is no output.

What am I missing?

**-my system-**

Ubuntu   20.04.1LTS x86-64
5.13.0-35

gcc/g++: 9.4.0

CPU:     Intel i9-12900KF

MEMORY:  32GB

Thanks for your attention.

I’m looking forward to any reply.

Answer (score 0):

I found what I missed from [This](https://gperftools.github.io/gperftools/cpuprofile.html) site!

The executable file must link by the `-lprofiler` option.

Then, I used `LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtprofiler.so` for hooking

a shared library without build.

Entire command

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtcmalloc.so:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprofiler.so CPUPROFILE=tcmalloc_python.prof python3 MNIST.py
```

(You must separate with ***`:`(colon)*** when using multiple libraries)

If you meet "**ERROR: ld.so: object '*libpath*' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored**" message, that must be don't exist library file in that path.

So, just reinstall pprof another way.

try

```
sudo apt install google-pprof-dev
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install golang-github-google-pprof-dev
```

and then, retry the above command(LD_PRELOAD~). It will work.

Referenced from [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=google-pprof-dev&searchon=names).

In my case, it works.

After training is done, some `.prof` file is generated!

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qt6rD.png)

But, pprof didn't work at python code(only c/c++ executable file)

I'll find another way. (Any idea?)

[pprof result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09wTI.png)

So, I found some test code from here and build an executable file.

Then tried pprof, It works! ([pprof manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/google-pprof.1.html))

[pprof result (success)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCm9N.jpg)